# Will this still work when passing in a _GET variable to a mysqli query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is the code that I was using in MySQL_ to pass in a variable from a search form. I am now using MySQLi_ and I wonder what would be the correct way to pass in the variable.

I currently have:

```
//Get the "Term" from the search box
    $query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);

    $page_str = "SELECT * FROM $tblname WHERE name like '%$query%' or clan like '%$query%'";

    $page_query = mysqli_query($con,$page_str)or die(mysql_error($con));
```

Comment: Should work, other than changing the $_GET to $_POST. Although, your code is quite liable to injection attacks. I'd recommend upgrading to using PDO, or similar.

Comment: Adapting with the times and preventative measures against sql injection is why I switched to MySqli_. The only part I am unclear about it passing the variable in though the search form. Examples on that to replace what I have above?

Comment: @Alex all your comments are wrong. This works with get as well as with post, he is protecting against injection by using real escape string (although the wrong one) and he's already using PDO or similar by using mysqli.

Comment: mysqli is still inferior to proper parameter binding in PDO, which is the recommended action/upgrade. Fair enough, mysqli is better than just mysql. The reason I said about changing $_GET to $_POST is because the original question was about $_POST. The op changed the question after my comment. Edit: as per the answer below - switch to prepared statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should use `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead to make that work.

As you will not have a `mysql_*` database connection open when you use `mysqli`, `mysql_real_escape_string` will not work.

However, I suggest you switch to prepared statements with bound variables and than you don't need that line at all.

Comment: Thank you. Just to be clear, changing to what you have typed to match that connection that I am using will do exactly what it is that I am trying to do right...and this will now fix there problem regardind the sql injections, correct?

Comment: @LinuxOwner Not really, see the comment in the manual about character sets: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php. You should just read up on prepared statements and use that.

Comment: I will def do that. I have been doing that in fact. I simply am just trying to get my search back together and running as it is on a live site. As it stands, everything works fine now as a basic query on test, I just am not yet able to pass in the variable from _GET.